# SDL Web 8.5 Publishing Failed in Deploying state

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, deployer

Useful for other community users for AWS cloud implementation.

**Issue:** 
Publishing got failed due to the high volume of pages published to publishing queue, CD deployer services memory usage maxed, tried restarted the CD services and tested republishing and next time DB memory usage went highly maxed.

**Deploying Failed Error:**

> Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed. Failed to execute
>   pipelineId: 'Tridion-Process-Deploy' for 'tcm:0-2030661-66560' because
>   of OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.

Deployer-worker micro service configured to use Blob storage is Redis.

```
<BinaryStorage Id="RedisStorage" Adapter="RedisBlobStorage">
    <Property Name="Host" Value="xxx.cache.xxx.com"/>
    <Property Name="Port" Value="6379"/>
    <Property Name="Timeout" Value="20000"/>
</BinaryStorage>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a Redis error. The deployer does not include any TTL values with blob's it places to Redis. Default configuration used for Redis cluster evicts data based on TTL values if not no evict option. The high volume of pages publishes maxed out the cache memory on the cluster.

We adjusted the eviction policy to remove data based on LRU instead. New group policy in redis is not "xxx-redis32" as oppose to the default of "default.redis3.2"

Comment: By the sound of it, you simply exhausted your Redis storage capacity (like running out of disk space on file system). So I don't think your solution should specify an eviction (on the contrary -- use 'no-eviction'), because you are then using Redis like a cache and you are going to lose on deployment packages. Instead, I would add more deployer workers, so they go through your binary packages backlog faster and thus not allowing Redis to reach 'maxmemory' limit.